# wp7 how can i import data (rss) from a feedburner link?

Tags: windows-phone-7, rss, feedburner

I just want, when my application start, to display at the home page the results of a feedburner link (like http:// feeds. feedburner. com / thesitename). My application is for wp7 and it use panorama style.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tried the above solution but it doesn't work

Comment: Your question includes no detail so what you've tried or what problem you're having. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I made an windows phone 7 application with panorama. I want in the first page/item of the panorama to show rss feed from a website, but i don't have xml, the only thing i have i a feedburner link like the above i wrote. I want to know if can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample from MSDN on [How to: Create a Basic RSS Reader for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487167%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works, but i can't see results, the application close when i push refresh feed. Also i don't want to push a button to see the results/feed, but i want the application to do it automatically when it opens.